# Efficient way to create UI for multipage forms in android

Tags: android

I was thinking if we have to create forms for the android tablets having fields like in the physical forms say Forms to open a Bank account or Insurance ie multiple page forms having same UI component well almost with exception to some may have others. So what is the best way to achieve this? Is it like default way of applying the UI components for required number of xml pages or any other ideas? Please let me know your suggestions.